# regexp for clear all style except text-align

Tags: php, regex

I have to clear all style attributes but not text-align:

```
$html_text='<td style="    width:297pt      ;  text-align:left; border-top:solid windowtext 0.5pt;border-right:solid windowtext 0.5pt;border-bottom:solid windowtext 0.5pt;border-left:solid windowtext 0.5pt;border-top:solid windowtext 0.5pt;border-right:solid windowtext 0.5pt;border-bottom:solid windowtext 0.5pt;border-left:solid windowtext 0.5pt;"><p style="direction:ltr;unicode-bidi:normal;text-autospace:none;">';
$html_text = 
preg_replace('/style=\"[^\"]*(text-align:[^;]+)+[^\"]*\"/', "style=\"$1\"",$html_text);



echo $html_text;
```

result:

```
<td style="text-align:left"><p style="direction:ltr;unicode-bidi:normal;text-autospace:none;">
```

any one regexp needed

I want to be

```
<td style="text-align:left"><p>
```

**UPDATE**

I found soluton. Not so elegant but works:

```
$html_text='<td style="    width:297pt      ;  text-align:left; border-top:solid windowtext 0.5pt;border-right:solid windowtext 0.5pt;border-bottom:solid windowtext 0.5pt;border-left:solid windowtext 0.5pt;border-top:solid windowtext 0.5pt;border-right:solid windowtext 0.5pt;border-bottom:solid windowtext 0.5pt;border-left:solid windowtext 0.5pt;"><p style="direction:ltr;unicode-bidi:normal;text-autospace:none;">';
$html_text = 
preg_replace('/style=\"[^\"]*(text-align:[^;]+)[^\"]*\"/', "styyy=\"$1\"",$html_text);
$html_text =preg_replace('/style=\"[^\"]*\"/', "",$html_text);
$html_text =str_replace('styyy', "style",$html_text);

echo $html_text;
```

Result as expected:

```
<td style="text-align:left"><p >
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need text-align, simply 'grab' the style attribute and everything between its quotations (valid CSS in this case) and replace it with the corrected style.

```
Match:         Replace:
style=".+?"    style="text-align:left"
```

Thus, your replace would be:

```
preg_replace('style=".+?"','style="text-align:left"',$html_text);
```

Comment: What if there is no `text-align:left` in original style? From what I see in that case OP also wants to remove `style` attribute.

Comment: yes. All works good if style consists text-align but if not - no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
preg_replace("'(<[^>]+?)style=(?P<encl>[\\'\"])[^\g{encl}]*(text-align:\s*(?:left|right|center))[^\g{encl}]*\g{encl}'isu", '$1style="$3"', $html_text);
```

to replace only tags with style attributes, but leave the text-align property. This will replace both attributes written like style="" and style=''

Comment: you just made it complicated! that shouldn't be long at all!

Comment: It's just more strict so it matches only tags and quotes, it could be simplified.